# How to get pid of some process started inside child process with help if exec family in C/C++ in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, exec

I want to get the pid of some process(let's call it Somebinary) which is started with the help of exec family inside child process and assume Somebinary never stops once started. I want to print the pid of this process from the parent process.

I can't wait in the parent process as the child process will start Somebinary through exec* and that will never stop. I know I can do:

```
int start(std::string Somebinary){
    pid_t childpid = fork();
    if(childpid == 0){
        freopen(logfile.c_str(), "a+", stdout);
        dup2(1, 2);

        exec*("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", Somebinary.c_str(), " &", NULL)
        exit(1);
    }
    // print pid of Somebinary from here
    return 0;
}
```

but I want to reduce extra overhead if possible.

Basically, I want to do the following thing as we do in bash from C/C++:

**Bash**

```
$ Somebinary > logfile 2>&1 &
$ pidof Somebinary
```

I know I can do stdout and stderr redirects with the help of freopen and dup2 in the child process. But the rest is the doubt.

P.S.: this has to be done in Linux

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Please show the rest of the code before the `exec`. Do you have a `fork` call? Basically you can `fork` before calling `exec` so that the parent process can the get the child process pid from the `fork` result. That's the usual way it is done.

Comment: Yes I do have fork before exec I'll edit code to include that part as well. @kaylum

Comment: `childpid` is the child pid already. What more do you need/want? `exec` does not change the pid. It *replaces* the process not make a new one.

Comment: Oh so does that mean pid of Somebinary will be childpid? @kaylum

Comment: It's `childpid`. Why do you think it is something different? As I said, `exec` does not change the pid.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know that, thanks a lot for the help @kaylum

Comment: What overhead do you want to reduce?

Comment: @stark invoking bash process which then calls binary process. I don't need bash process, I can directly call binary.

Comment: Note that the process you are starting is sh

Comment: The & means fork again and run the process in background.

Comment: That is why I want to remove sh as middle person. @stark

Comment: So just exec SomeBinary. You don't need sh or &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `exec` does not "create a process" or change the PID, `fork` does.

As @kaylum said, `childpid` is the PID of the exec'd process already. You can just print it:

```
int start(std::string Somebinary){
    pid_t childpid = fork();
    if(childpid == 0){
        freopen(logfile.c_str(), "a+", stdout);
        dup2(1, 2);

        exec(Somebinary.c_str(), NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (childpid < 0) { // basic error handling
        perror("fork"); return -1;
    }
    // print pid of Somebinary from here
    printf("childpid = %jd\n", (intmax_t) childpid);
    return 0;
}
```

Also you might want to bypass `/bin/sh` and `exec` the `Somebinary` directly, otherwise you'll get the PID of `/bin/sh`.